# Aurora - Large Table - is DROP COLUMN a locking operation

Tags: mysql, database, ddl, amazon-aurora

I am running 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.04.9 and have a very large table.

I'd like to drop a single column from this table but I am unsure whether it will lock the table or not.

The column is not indexed or part of a key.

If it was just raw MySQL 5.7 I'd say no, but I am a bit unsure about the differences with Aurora.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-operations - dropping column performs table rebuild and hence locks it during the process.